# How to cancel the CompletableFuture owned by Mono.fromFuture(Supplier)?

Tags: project-reactor

The [documentation for `Mono.fromFuture(Supplier)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromFuture-java.util.function.Supplier-) says:

> Note that the future is not cancelled when that Mono is cancelled, but
> that behavior can be obtained by using a doFinally(Consumer) that
> checks for a SignalType.CANCEL and calls
> CompletableFuture.cancel(boolean).

How do you get a reference to the future returned by the supplier?

```
public static <T> Mono<T> toMono(Supplier<CompletableFuture<T>> supplier) {
  return Mono.fromFuture(supplier)
      .doFinally(signal -> {
        if (signal == SignalType.CANCEL) {
          // ??????
        }
      })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [`Mono.defer()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defer-java.util.function.Supplier-), getting the future from the supplier myself, and passing it to the version of `Mono.fromFuture` that takes a future instead of a supplier.

The resulting Mono is cold (as long as the supplier returns a new future each time) and propagates cancellation to the future.

```
public static <T> Mono<T> toMono(Supplier<CompletableFuture<T>> supplier) {
  return Mono.defer(() -> {
    CompletableFuture<T> future = supplier.get();
    return Mono.fromFuture(future)
        .doFinally(signal -> {
          if (signal == SignalType.CANCEL) {
            future.cancel(true);
          }
        })
  });
}
```